# nuget package-update performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

i am using nuget-packages to separate my asp.net-mvc web-application into modules (each area is a separate package).
i needed to do this because its a multi-tenant system where each customer can have his own implementation of the modules.

But when i change something in my modules i need to rebuild them => create the nuget-package and then update the package in my main-application.
My problem is, that updating these packages takes painfully long. My test-module has only about 50kB (3 Views to copy located in the content folder of the package) and it still takes about 3 minutes to update.
The package-source is just a local folder, so it shouldnt be a network-related issue.

Any ideas on how to improve the performance or what i'm doing wrong?